# Mozilla system default style - *|*:-moz-any-link

Tags: css, firefox, hyperlink

For some reason, Firefox renders a purple visited link around the outside of the logo at the top. My attempt to specify a:visited  {text-decoration: none;} doesn't seem to phase Firefox. What's going on here?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You are showing us the wrong styles - links are only underlined below the text. The screenshot shows the effect of either `border` or `outline`. So you will either need to look for other styles applying here or give us an example we could look at ourselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images inside links show a border by default.

Use `a img{border:0;}`